# Drupal 7: How do I change the input format of a Date after the field was created?

Tags: drupal-7, cck, datefield

I created a "Date" field and its format defaulted to MM/DD/YYYY (English). I changed the Date settings in "/admin/config/regional/date-time" to use DD/MM/YYYY and added another "Date" field, which uses that format. Now I have two fields with two different date formats and I have no clue how to set them both to DD/MM/YYYY.

Any idea ?

Comment: I think there is a similar question over here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/47709/change-date-format-for-the-example-dates-given-below-date-field

Answer (score 0):

I believe your best practice would be:

1. converting your corresponding database tables
2. exporting these tables
3. deleting this field form your site
4. running cron
5. creating this field from scratch and setting it to use your new format
6. overwriting your corresponding tables with the converted (original) tables in DB

You need to convert your tables after you have saved them. You can not change them once you have them, only conversation works normally.